# After upgrading chrome to 83, the browser blocked the response of the server interface

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, cross-origin-opener-policy, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-resource-policy

chrome 81

The server is configured with a response header
  'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy':'same-origin',
  'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy':'require-corp',

No problem with the browser's access to the server's interface

chrome 83

The server is configured with a response header
  'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy':'same-origin',
  'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy':'require-corp',

My browser accessing the interface of the server returns an error:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

After the response header is added to the server interface, the interface can be accessed normally.
 'Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy':'cross-origin'

Some of our interfaces require third-party interfaces, such as AWS upload. We cannot configure'Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy':'cross-origin' for these interfaces
This will cause upload failure using AWS. Is there any solution to this situation?

Comment: Did you find a solution here? I have a similar issue.